# Unpack array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, polymer

I have the following code:

```
let filters = []
this.query.split(" ").forEach(function(word){
    // ...
    filters.push(value)
}

this.push('filters', DOUBT);
```

In Polymer, I can do `this.push('filters', value1, value2, value3)` in order to push three values to an array property at the same time. The problem is that I don't know how many words the user query would be composed by.

I can't do `this.push('filters', value)` for each word of my query because my `filters` property has an observer and I don't want the function to be launched multiple times. Finally, I neither can do `this.push('filters', filters)` since this will save an array inside an array.

Is there any function in JavaScript which unpacks an array and gives all its elements? I'm looking for something similar to `this.push('filters', filters*)`

Comment: what is `value`

Comment: Use the spread syntax: `this.push('filters', ...filters)`.

Comment: Its a dictionary @brk

Comment: like trincot suggestion, look at the spread operator; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: That was exactly what I was asking for, but I didn't know the name of the operator to search it. Thank you very much @trincot